# Formula field doesn't fire trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I have two objects called Opportunity and Tournee, with a date field and date field is a formula field which subtracts 10 days from date field in Opportunity and the trigger create events based on this dates and shows them in a calendar. Now, what I found is Tournee trigger is not being called on its date formula field update. Now how do i create Tournee events based on its date field?

Comment: Please, share your trigger code so we can see what you've attempted, and why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @smukov  the code is too big with other functionalities, now all that i want is how to fire a trigger on Cross-Object Formula field update.

Comment: a formula field update on it's own is not enough, you need a DML action with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Formula fields aren't really being `updated` per se, but instead, they are just evaluated when you perform a query against the record.

Because of this, if you have two objects A and B, and you have a cross-object formula field on object B that is referencing a field on object A. If you update a record A, you are probably expecting that the record B gets updated as well due to the cross-object formula field, however, this won't be the case. Instead, the record B will calculate the new formula value **only** when you query for the record, or simply open the record detail page.

Thus, if you want to fire a `trigger` in this case on object B, the only option you have is to actually create a `trigger` on object A, query for the related B records inside the object A's `trigger`, and do whatever you need to do with those records.

Comment: So you want me to replace formula field with trigger ?

Comment: No, leave the formula field on `Tournee`, but you can't use a trigger on that object. You need to create a trigger on `Opportunity` instead. Then, inside the `Opportunity` trigger you need to do your thing that you are currently trying to achieve in `Tournee` trigger.

Comment: The key thing to understand is that trigger on `Tournee` object won't be fired when a Date field on `Opportunity` is updated, because formula fields do not cause a trigger to be fired. You need to use the `Opportunity` trigger instead to get the related `Tournee` records and then perform the required logic on them.